# Can someone help me determine why the values are not being defined?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm new to coding and trying to really get a solid grasp of Javascript basics. The prompt was to create a function that takes in an array of animal objects and returns a new array with a sentence about each animal.

The object is:

```js
const animals = [
  { name: "Waffles", type: "dog", age: 7 },
  { name: "Fluffy", type: "cat", age: 14 },
  { name: "Spelunky", type: "dog", age: 4 },
  { name: "Hank", type: "cat", age: 11 }
]
```

My function is:

```js
const sentence = (array) => {
  return array.map((object) => {
    return `The ${animals.name} is a ${animals.type} and it        is ${animals.age} years old.`
  })
}
```

When I print in terminal using

```js
console.log(sentence(animals))
```

I'm getting the following result:

```js
[
  'The undefined is a undefined and it is undefined years old.',
  'The undefined is a undefined and it is undefined years old.',
  'The undefined is a undefined and it is undefined years old.',
  'The undefined is a undefined and it is undefined years old.'
]
```

So it's mapping over the object and doing something to each value (returning the sentence) but not reading the key: value pairs. I tried refactoring but got the same result.

Comment: As to getting a solid grasp of JavaScript basics, I highly recommend [_JavaScript for impatient programmers_](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/index.html) (and, really, all the books there on [Exploring JS](https://exploringjs.com/index.html)). And, if you don't mind spending some money, [Just JavaScript](https://justjavascript.com) is _fantastic_ for getting a good mental model of how the language itself works.

Comment: The [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org) (formerly just the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)) are a great reference for specific things, especially browser APIs and such. The also have a [JavaScript guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript).

Comment: [Eloquent JavaScript](https://eloquentjavascript.net) is also very good. It helps build a mental model and teaches a bit about programming itself and how computers work.

Comment: And for "a series of books diving deep into the core mechanisms of the JavaScript language", I really like [_You Don't Know JS Yet_](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) by Kyle Simpson.

Comment: Thanks a lot for those suggestions, will definitely check them out

Answer (score 2):

Use the first argument (the current element) in the `map` callback instead of trying to access those properties on the array itself.

```js
const animals = [
{ name: "Waffles", type: "dog", age: 7 },
{ name: "Fluffy", type: "cat", age: 14 },
{ name: "Spelunky", type: "dog", age: 4 },
{ name: "Hank", type: "cat", age: 11 }
]
const sentence = array => array.map(object => 
  `The ${object.name} is a ${object.type} and it is ${object.age} years old.`);
console.log(sentence(animals));
```

Comment: Thank you! The parameter/placeholder is still a little tricky for me but I understand now why this was not reading correctly